# Where can I find the resources for creating AIML files for chatbot?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, aiml

I am trying to build a custom chatbot and having difficulties in finding guidelines and resources for AIML creation.
What I want is kind of manual for the usage of tags and predicates.
Any suggesstions!
Really appericate.

Answer (score 2):

Get it from the "horse's mouth" or rather Alice's mouth ;-)   at [**alicebot.org**](http://www.alicebot.org/documentation/)
You may find the [***AIML Tag reference manual***](http://www.alicebot.org/documentation/aiml-reference.html) particularly relevant to your quest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a complete beginner to aiml then refer to [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/aiml/)'s website for basic tags understanding.

If done with it now you can look at other peoples codes for reference and create your own chatbots.
You can a [look at some of the files here](http://www.mitsuku.com/).

Go to free aiml files and refer them.

You can start building your bot using the following

- Use pyaiml interpretor you can download it from sourceforge website
- You can use program o download its zip files from GitHub
- You can also build using pandorabot website. It hosts chatbots.

Good luck.